# Problemas al filtrar datos desde un formulario con PHP y Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

expongo mi problema por lo cual escribo por este medio.
estoy creando un sistema el cual el usuario lista unos registros que vienen de una base de datos, en el frontend le muestro todos los datos en una tabla, arriba de la tabla que muestra los datos esta un formulario para filtrar la información que el usuario esta viendo, he visto los métodos para filtrar según los criterios que el usuario desee, los aplique y me da como resultado que me toma en cuenta algunos filtros y otros no, el siguiente codigo son los criterios que he aplicado para el filtro:

```
// filtros de busqueda
    $where = '';
    if (isset($_POST['filtrar'])) {

        //filtra remitente y destinatario
        if(!empty($_POST['r_nombre']) && !empty($_POST['d_nombre'])){

            $where=" WHERE r_nombre LIKE '%".$_POST['r_nombre']."%' OR r_apellido LIKE '%".$_POST['r_nombre']."%' OR d_nombre LIKE '%".$_POST['d_nombre']."%' OR d_apellido LIKE '%".$_POST['d_nombre']."%'  ";

        //filtra solo remitente
        }elseif(!empty($_POST['r_nombre']) && empty($_POST['d_nombre'])){

            $where=" WHERE r_nombre LIKE '%".$_POST['r_nombre']."%' OR r_apellido LIKE '%".$_POST['r_nombre']."%' ";

        //filtra solo destinatario
        }elseif(empty($_POST['r_nombre']) && !empty($_POST['d_nombre'])){

            $where=" WHERE d_nombre LIKE '%".$_POST['d_nombre']."%' OR d_apellido LIKE '%".$_POST['d_nombre']."%' ";

        //filtra desde - hasta
        }elseif(!empty($_POST['desde']) && !empty($_POST['hasta'])){

            $where="WHERE llegada_wh BETWEEN '$_POST[desde]' AND '$_POST[hasta]' ";

        //filtra por guía
        }elseif(!empty($_POST['guia'])){

            $where=" WHERE track LIKE '%".$_POST['guia']."%'";

        //filtra por status
        }elseif(!empty($_POST['estatus'])){

            $where=" WHERE status_guia = '$_POST[estatus]'";

        //filtra por tipo de cobro
        }elseif(!empty($_POST['tipo_cobro'])){

            $where=" WHERE tipo_cobro = '$_POST[tipo_cobro]'";

        //filtra el remitente por nro de guia y estatus
        }elseif(!empty($_POST['r_nombre']) && !empty($_POST['guia']) && !empty($_POST['estatus']) ){

            $where=" WHERE r_nombre LIKE '".$_POST['r_nombre']."%' OR r_apellido LIKE '".$_POST['r_nombre']."%' AND track LIKE '%".$_POST['guia']."%' AND status_guia = '$_POST[estatus]' ";

        }

    }
```

y aqui la consulta que me trae los datos

```
$sql_limit = "SELECT track,llegada_wh,r_apellido,r_nombre,r_tlf,d_nombre,d_apellido,d_tlf,status_guia,peso_cobrado,total_guia,contenedores,tarifa,unidad,tipo_cobro FROM guias $where ORDER BY fecha_creacion DESC LIMIT $empezar_desde,$cant_mostrar";
    $datos_limit = $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql_limit);
    $row_limit = $datos->num_rows;
```

mi pregunta es: estoy aplicando el método correcto o habrá algún otro método de filtrar la información

aquí están los input que reciben los datos

```
<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"r_nombre\" placeholder=\"nombre o apellido\">
<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"d_nombre\" placeholder=\"nombre o apellido\">
<input type=\"date\" name=\"desde\" class=\"form-control\">
<input type=\"date\" name=\"hasta\" class=\"form-control\">
<input type=\"text\" name=\"guia\" class=\"form-control\">
<select name=\"estatus\" class=\"form-control\">
                                    <option>Seleccione...</option>";
                                    while ($row_estatus = $datos_estatus->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        echo"                          
                                        <option value=\"$row_estatus[estatus]\">$row_estatus[estatus]</option>";               
                                        }                                        
                                    echo "    
                                    </select>
<select name=\"tipo_cobro\" class=\"form-control\">
                                        <option>Seleccione...</option>
                                        <option value=\"Cobro en destino\">C.O.D.</option>
                                        <option value=\"Pre-Pagado\">Pre-Pagado</option>
                                    </select>
```

Comment: Por lo pronto te diria  que no concatenes lo que te llega desde el formulario en tu string de la query, ya que quedas expuesto a vulnerabilidades de SQL inyection. Te recomiendo que investigues un poco PDO y bindValue, por ejemplo aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: ¿Por qué no dices cuáles filtros funcionan o cuáles no? Luego, en el planteamiento de la pregunta no queda claro si los filtros se aplican sobre datos que ya han sido traídos del servidor o si mandas a buscar los datos cada vez que se aplica un filtro. Conviene que seas más claro explicando la forma en que funciona tu programa para poder ayudarte mejor. Gracias.